# Using a XAML Image as a WPF Window background

Tags: wpf, image, xaml, background, window

Any suggestions how to go about having a XAML vector image as a Window background? There's plenty of code showing this with jpg's but I'd prefer a vector based image.

Having it as a resource would be a bonus too but I'm stumped as to the best approach.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Viewbox x:Key="Background2" Stretch="Fill">
        <Canvas >
            <!-- Ebene 1/<Path> -->
            <Path Fill="#ff000000" Data="F1 M 841.890,595.275 L 0.000,595.275 L 0.000,0.000 L 841.890,0.000 L 841.890,595.275 Z"/>
            <!-- Ebene 1/<Path> -->
            <Path Data="F1 M 265.910,218.277 C 265.910,169.332 223.865,129.655 172.000,129.655 C 120.135,129.655 78.090,169.332 78.090,218.277 C 78.090,267.222 120.135,306.898 172.000,306.898 C 223.865,306.898 265.910,267.222 265.910,218.277 Z">
                <Path.Fill>
                    <RadialGradientBrush MappingMode="Absolute" GradientOrigin="172.733,217.234" Center="172.733,217.234" RadiusX="81.912" RadiusY="81.912">
                        <RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                            <GradientStop Offset="0.00" Color="#ff0d4976"/>
                            <GradientStop Offset="0.41" Color="#ff06243b"/>
                            <GradientStop Offset="1.00" Color="#ff000000"/>
                        </RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                        <RadialGradientBrush.Transform>
                            <MatrixTransform Matrix="1.146,0.000,0.000,1.082,-26.038,-16.750" />
                        </RadialGradientBrush.Transform>
                    </RadialGradientBrush>
                </Path.Fill>
            </Path>
        </Canvas>
    </Viewbox>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The Resource code above works fine if you remove the Viewbox. The code for the window is :-

```
  <Window x:Class="Window2"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window2" Height="700" Width="800">
        <Window.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Dictionary2.xaml" />
        </Window.Resources>
        <Grid>
         <StaticResource ResourceKey="Background2"/>   
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Canvas x:Key="Background2">
        <!-- Ebene 1/<Path> -->
        <Path Fill="#ff000000" Data="F1 M 841.890,595.275 L 0.000,595.275 L 0.000,0.000 L 841.890,0.000 L 841.890,595.275 Z"/>
        <!-- Ebene 1/<Path> -->
        <Path Data="F1 M 265.910,218.277 C 265.910,169.332 223.865,129.655 172.000,129.655 C 120.135,129.655 78.090,169.332 78.090,218.277 C 78.090,267.222 120.135,306.898 172.000,306.898 C 223.865,306.898 265.910,267.222 265.910,218.277 Z">
            <Path.Fill>
                <RadialGradientBrush MappingMode="Absolute"
                           GradientOrigin="172.733,217.234"
                           Center="172.733,217.234"
                           RadiusX="81.912" RadiusY="81.912">
                    <RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                        <GradientStop Offset="0.00" Color="#ff0d4976"/>
                        <GradientStop Offset="0.41" Color="#ff06243b"/>
                        <GradientStop Offset="1.00" Color="#ff000000"/>
                    </RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                    <RadialGradientBrush.Transform>
                        <MatrixTransform 
                             Matrix="1.146,0.000,0.000,1.082,-26.038,-16.750" />
                    </RadialGradientBrush.Transform>
                </RadialGradientBrush>
            </Path.Fill>
        </Path>
    </Canvas>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid >
    <Grid.Background>
        <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{StaticResource Background2}" />
    </Grid.Background>
</Grid>
```

You will just have to make a couple of changes to move the resource to your resource dictionary if absolutely necessary.

Comment: Cheers Simon, I'd almost given up on this one. Your solution worked first time. I'm now considering moving it to a resource dictionary so I can have a selection of backgrounds that are user selectable. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of tools, including Illustrator, allow you to export XAML images in different formats. Your ideal goal is a `ResourceDictionary` that contains a `Canvas` or `Grid` panel, that contains your vector image. Then you could reference the dictionary in your `Window.Resources` and simply add the image panel (which is a `Canvas` or `Grid`) to your top-level Window panel.

So your image .XAML file needs to look something like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Canvas x:Name="MyXamlImage">
        ...
    </Canvas>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then in your `Window` you should have something like:

```
<Window x:Class="YourNamespace.YourWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="YourWindow" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="MyResourceDictionary.xaml">
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <StaticResource ResourceKey="MyXamlImage"/>
        ...
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Hi Charlie, that kinda works but the Canvas size is fixed and I need it to resize with the window. Previously I had put the canvas in a Viewbox with Stretch="Fill" so it resized, but I'm not sure how to adapt this using your method. Any ideas?

Comment: You can still wrap the Canvas in a Viewbox. Just make the Viewbox the top element of your ResourceDictionary, and give it a name instead of the Canvas.

Comment: Tried making the Viewbox the top element but it now doesn't show up at all. Very strange..

Comment: Added some sample code. I have to use a x:Key not a x:Name or I get the error "All objects added to an IDictionary must have a Key attribute or some other type of key associated with them." All works well with Canvas, but when I wrap it with a Viewbox, nothing shows.